# What to use other than listview?

Tags: android

Anyone knows how the center part is being listed? I tried using listview but it does not have a space large enough for the image

[image]

Comment: Using a custom listview you can do anything you want

Comment: Indeed it looks like a Custom ListView.

Comment: It is a list view, with custom views as list items

Comment: You will have to implement this with Custom Listview Adapter and design the layout like mentioned screenshot. Check out demo http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92

Comment: @DM Poh Ann Check out my answer.

Comment: Thanks for all your reply, i'm currently reading the demo now! Really thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to customize the normal behavior of the `ListView`. The layout you see inside each row, is a separate layout file prepared, that contains some TextViews, ImageViews, and that layout file is inflated as a row of the `ListView`.

Check out this example: http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92

Very nicely explained how we can customize a `ListView`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would be able to use a scrollview then just add some views and layouts inside it.

Comment: I didnt down vote but in this case you should not use `ScrollView`, as length of the list is dynamic. Hence, when more data will be added to ScrollView, it will become heavier. At some stage ScrollView's perfomance will be decreased, and application also may get stuck or crash.

Answer (score 0):

If you create you own list adapter you can inflate all kinds of views inside a normal listview

```
extends ArrayAdapter<Object>
```

And  overwrite the `getView` method

Answer (score 0):

You can have look at [PintrestListViewAdapter](https://github.com/huewu/PinterestLikeAdapterView) which is opensource

Check out the Implementation demo [HERE](https://github.com/chenyoca/pinterest-like-adapter-view)